# body background using sprite

Tags: css

I'm changing my site to use one sprite image instead of many individual images.

so the first thing on my sprite (1000 x 2000 px) is the background image, which is 100 x 2000 px.

what the css look like to do a repeat-x only for the first 100px?

thanks

Comment: `what the css look like to do a repeat-x only for the first 100px?` you have answered your own question. do repeat-x and specify the width and height which in your case 100 x 2000 px.. what else do you need?

Comment: set the width of the body to 100px?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best solution is making 3 sprites.

main-sprite.png (1000x2000 for all icons and images)

x-sprite.png (1px width) use it for all repeat-x backgrounds

y-sprite.png (1px height) use it for all repeat-y backgrounds

Comment: my background uses a 100px pattern which repeats, so in this case I need it to be 100px. are you saying that x-sprite.png is my background image in this case (i.e not really an image sprite)?

Comment: Yes exactly. However you can add other repeat-x backgrounds to the x-repeat.png. (if you have any) It doesn't matter if you change its width to 100px in this case.

Comment: Have a look at this sprite from amazon.com. If you want to apply repeat-x to any image, that image should fill the whole width of the sprite image.
http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/common/sprites/sprite-site-wide-2._V146303866_.png

Comment: thank you @CodingWay. I was ok with other html elements, but was not sure if it could be done with a sprite on the body itself. Just trying to keep the images to one image sprite, that's all. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

three solutions:

1- change your contsturction of your sprite image, instead of using 1000x2000 use 100xwhatever you want sprite image and stack the other icons and images in the bottom

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background:url('yourspriteimage.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x; width:100px;height:2000px;background-position:0px 0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
your content here
</body>
</html>
```

2- do not sprite your background image.

3- create three sprite images (one for x-repeat only, one for y-repeat only, on for no-repeat)

Comment: no, it doesn't work because you're setting the width of the body tag to 100px (your css has it backwards, but who cares about the details), which means that all page content must fit within 100px, which it doesn't. Hence, my reply to you "set the width of the body to 100px", after your second comment making fun of the question.

Comment: @IIS7Rewrite Rewrite fixed it